# ping flood weird behavior? After a bunch of timeouts, the rate increases 30x

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, ping, packet-loss

I have a weird behaviour that I don't really understand why it is happening. While troubleshooting why I had periodic packet loss over wifi on my macbook, I noticed a different, strange behaviour.

When running a ping flood (ping -f gateway_ip) initially it fires of with a send rate of approx. 30-40kb/s.

If I trigger a packet loss sequence by doing a wifi scan (airport -s), a bunch of packets will be dropped due to the wifi card being busy with scanning for wifis. So far, I understand what is happening.

But then, after this has happen, the sustained network utilization for this ping flood is 1.7MB/s, increased by 40-50x?! The flood ping continues to be fairly stable, without major drops. If I stop it, and restart it, it is back down to 30-40kb/s again. This is very consistent.

Now, I tried doing the same within Docker on a linux container (on the same machine). There I see that the ping packet responses are delayed, but eventually catches up (not timing out) when doing a wifi scan. The ping rate (30kb/s) is sustained even after this hickup.

Anybody have a theory what is going on?